# How to collapse parent with BigNerdRanch Expand Recyclerview library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Working with Big Nerd Ranch recycler:expand library

`'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'`

In `RecyclerAdapter.Java` code...

```
 @Override
public void onParentItemClickListener(int position) {
    /**
     * @Params
     * Se comienza en -1, al clickear el primer grupo, se registra en la variable su posicion
     * al clickear el siguiente grupo, si la variable no es igual a su posicion se procede a
     * cerrar el grupo anterior.
     * */

    Object parent = mParentItemList.get(position);
    //Toast.makeText(mContext,"posicion "+String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(lastExpanded == -1){
        lastExpanded = position;

    } else if(lastExpanded == position){
        lastExpanded = -1; //Reinicia Variable

        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }else{
        //Cierra grupo abierto
        int oldExpand = lastExpanded;
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"se cerro  "+String.valueOf(oldExpand),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lastExpanded = position;

        **//Need the colapse group code**

        notifyItemChanged(oldExpand);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    super.onParentItemClickListener(position);
}
```

I need how to collapse group after clicking another parentGroup.

Comment: Have you check on their guide? https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Comment: And this on their blog https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/

Comment: But note that this library has been deprecated. Feature development and bug fixing is no longer planned. Feel free to fork for your development.

Answer (score 0):

Only update library

```
'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
```

to

```
'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
```

and refactor(edit) name java classes.